# CakePHP 1.3: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] Issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an issue with using the following code in my CakePHP app.

In my development server(@ home):

- When I use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, I get: `/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/webroot/`

On my production server (a2hosting), which is an exact duplicate of my application:

- The same code returns `/home/xxxxxx/public_html/`

Why is that happening and how can I quickly fix it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the global `WWW_ROOT` instead. It is set by CakePHP.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are checking same file on both servers.
At your home development server your apache configuration (httpd.conf) needs to be editied.

```
DocumentRoot /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/
```